# Working with Input + keyup + value and then giphy

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get whatever user search via input after he will stop typing. Then i would like to pass it to giphy api but there i have a problem with passing variable/result. Here is my code :

```js
const mainInput = document.querySelector(".main-input");
mainInput.addEventListener('keyup', getUserQuery);

function getUserQuery(e) {
    let timeout = null;
    let userQuery;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        return userQuery = mainInput.value;
    },300)
    return userQuery;
}

//function makeUrlForSearch(getUserQuery) {
//    let a = getUserQuery();
//    console.log(a);
//}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.header {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem auto; 
}

.header-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Wyszkuj Gipha!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header"><h1 class="header-title">Wyszukaj Gipha!</h1></header>
    <main class="main">
        <form class="main-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Wyszukaj Gipha!" class="main-input" id="main-input">
        </form>
    </main>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the makerUrlForSearch is not working and i've beend siting on it for a while but its not working.

Can anyone help? So that i would get search made by user after 300ms after he stops typing and then use it in giphy api, but i cannot do it :(

Comment: Roger setTimeout is here to get users input after he will stop typing. makeUrlForSearch does nothing yet but it will but result from getUserQuery and make it giphy search url :)

Answer (score 1):

Below you can find a solution to your problem by using `debounce` function from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce)

I have made changes below. Added a raw debounce function.

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
 var timeout;
 return function() {
  var context = this, args = arguments;
  var later = function() {
   timeout = null;
   if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
  };
  var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
  if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
 };
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  function makeUrlForSearch(query) {
     let a = query;
      console.log(a);
  }
  function getUserQuery(e) {
      makeUrlForSearch(e.target.value);
  }
 document.querySelector(".main-input").addEventListener('keyup', debounce(getUserQuery, 300));
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.header {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem auto; 
}

.header-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Wyszkuj Gipha!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header"><h1 class="header-title">Wyszukaj Gipha!</h1></header>
    <main class="main">
        <form class="main-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Wyszukaj Gipha!" class="main-input" id="main-input">
        </form>
    </main>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Vasile since im trying to learn vanilla js could You please provide answear in vanilla js so i can learn most?

Comment: This is vanilla javascript including lodash's debounce function, which is written in vanilla javascript. You should not be afraid to use libraries to achieve your objectives. If you want to learn you can look into lodash's debounce function here https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a debounce function

Comment: Thx @Vasile for help

Comment: No worries. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple issues in the code you provided :

- In `getUserQuery` function, you're returning `userQuery` before the asynchronous `setTimeOut` sets its value.
- The `makeUrlForSearch` function is calling getUserQuery but is never called. I switched that and made it so `getUserQuery` calls the `makeUrlForSearch` function
- In `getUserQuery`, the timeout declaration would always erase previous timeouts. I moved the `let timeout = null` instruction outside of your `getUserQuery` function to make it global so that a `getUserQuery` call can clear a previous timeout.

```js
const mainInput = document.querySelector(".main-input");
mainInput.addEventListener('keyup', getUserQuery);
let timeout;

function getUserQuery(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        makeUrlForSearch(mainInput.value);
    },300);
}

function makeUrlForSearch(getUserQuery) {
    //let a = getUserQuery();
    console.log(getUserQuery);
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.header {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem auto; 
}

.header-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Wyszkuj Gipha!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header"><h1 class="header-title">Wyszukaj Gipha!</h1></header>
    <main class="main">
        <form class="main-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Wyszukaj Gipha!" class="main-input" id="main-input">
        </form>
    </main>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank U RogerC. Is it the cleanest solution? will i be able to use value from makeUrlForSearch in another function without any problem?

Comment: No, you can't use the value passed to `makeUrlForSearch`. It's a parameter and it's local to `makeUrlForSearch`. But you can call another function, either from your timeout delayed function (in `getUserQuery`) or from `makeUrlForSearch`.

Comment: Thx @RogerC i cannot upvote it cause i dont have enough reputation :(

Comment: Wow, someone upvote my question so i was able to upvote Yours answear :)